# The role of runtime exceptions in defining a methods “contract” and expressing the intentions of an operation and a classes ADT

Tags: java, oop, exception

Could it be said that RuntimeException's may play a role in defining an operation, as part of the notion of a classes ADT and a particular operations "contract".

Since one **chooses** to include chosen runtime exceptions in the 'throws' list in a methods header (as well as a methods javadoc) - *it is not forced by the compiler and is discretionary depending upon the exception* - could this not be considered an effort to emphasize something about the intention of a methods "contract" and how it should be understood to work? Is this the case?

We recognize that some RuntimeExceptions's are simply thrown as "errors" for program logic that needs correcting during development and testing, whereas others could be considered to perform a similar role to that of checked exceptions. Here by embodying instances where a handleable and recoverable situation may occur - a client user should be able to take some reasonable action to allow the sw system to recover and respond appropriately. One designs an ADT and an operation to emphasize how it should be used. I wondered (considering the above) if we should consider as part of this:

"The conveying to the client developer of the need to handle certain Runtime Exception's that can sensibly be handled and anticipated"?

Do we consider the declaration of RuntimeException's in an operations header and documentation to be signalling such an intention and expectation by the code/ API developer to the client user?

Emphasizing the RuntimeExceptions it may throw by declaring them in a throws section (that one should thus handle) and or, declaring them in a javadoc (that one should instead potentially just be aware of) could perhaps be considered as part of this “contract” - that one should understand and uphold in defining and working with an interface (an operation). Therefore, by choosing to emphasize certain RuntimeExceptions (which are a choice), could this therefore be a part of the concept of "design by contract" that one shapes and expresses – it is about intention (what a method should provide as a service, but (pertinant here) - how the method is intended to be used by a client and his/ her expected responsibilities)?

Also, if/ or what, is the relationship between the throwing and documenting of Runtime Exceptions and the software design principle of design by contract is?

Another way of looking at my question i suppose is - One **can** catch a runtime exception if desired. I think the vast majority of cases where a runtime exception might occur and is thrown relate to situations that never or should never occur in correct client code. Most of these situations relate to incorrect logic or misuse of a method (and handling code would be excessively numerous and not sensible to include in these situations). However, in some less frequent cases, it is possible for some runtime exceptions to be situations that one could (and should) handle. This is why I think (I interpret I coud be wrong), the compiler doesn't require one to handle runtime exceptions - the compiler cannot tell the difference. It cannot distinguish. Checked exceptions are almost always sensibly handleable, but most runtime exceptions are likely not. The nature of a runtime error governs this. – Another angle on my question I suppose relates to the notion that the latter can sometimes be the case and are we supposed to consider this as part of the contract we emphasize as described above and the software design principle of "design by contract"?

Comment: should one re-throw (with a checked exception) in cases where runtime exceptions could be handled sensibly and the API author intends them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither the throws clause is required by the Compiler for subclasses of RuntimeException if you throw one in a method, nor is it required to catch them if you call such a method, it is just for documentation.

Comment: I see. But one **can** catch a runtime exception if desired. I think the vast majority of cases where a runtime exception might occur and is thrown relate to situations that never or should never occur in correct client code. Most of these situations relate to incorrect logic or misuse of a method (and handling code would be excessively numerous and not sensible to include in these situations). However, in some less frequent cases, it is possible for some runtime exceptions to be situations that one could (and should) handle. This is why I think (I interpret I coud be wrong), the

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String) throws NumberFormatException (which is a subclass of RuntimeException). If you read the Content of a file and call this method, your code can be perfectly fine, but if the files Content just does not contain proper Integers, you will get that exception. So even if you and your Team would agree to that convention you described above, some libraries wouldnt do, so I think the convention would not be very helpful.

Comment: compiler doesn't require one to handle runtime exceptions - the compiler cannot tell the difference. It cannot distinguish. Checked excpetions are almost always sensibly handleable, but most runtime exceptions are likely not. The nature of a runtime error governs this. - My question I suppose, relates to the notion that the latter can sometimes be the case and are  we supposed to consider this as part of the contract we emphasize as described above and the software design principle of "design by contract"?

Comment: should one re-throw (with a checked exception) in cases where runtime exceptions could be handled sensibly and the API author intends them to be. Such as perhaps in the case of NumberFormatException, for instanvces such as the one you gave above?

Comment: Many thanks for answering, the scenario you reffered to was the kind I was thinking of. Rather than having your program terminate upon such an exception, one would hope perhaps it would attempt to role back to a safe state, save work/ data, attempt to recover or pause an alternative action.